# model is a variable but is used as a Type OfType<model>()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to get the model a page is looking to and send data based on the Model received. I have tried the following code but it says **'model'** is a variable but is used as a Type

```
public IActionResult GetComments(string modelName)
        {
Type model = Type.GetType(modelName+", UHDMS.Models");
                var mapping = _context.Model.FindEntityType(model);
                tablename = mapping.GetTableName();

                var props = _context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Single(e => (e.GetTableName().OfType<model>()).Equals(tablename)).GetProperties();

}
```

Note: error is happening on this line e.GetTableName().OfType()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: Can you post _context code.